# Is there any way to upload application automatic for Android Market?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I would like to upload Auto generated `.apk` file to Android market directly by providing credential. so is there any way available to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is currently no API for this. And probably with good reason, because no one want spammy rubber-stamped apps being uploaded automatically.

Comment: hmm you might be correct as google don't have any application filter software running at the time of app upload like apple app store.

Comment: Actually they do. It runs the apps in a sandbox environment and tries to determine if they are malicious. Not 100% effective thought, as numerous researchers have shown. See this for details: https://blog.duosecurity.com/2012/06/dissecting-androids-bouncer/